# Used tires of same sku but different tread depth in Magento

Tags: magento

In Magento, I'm trying to set up new AND used tires, the requirements being:

1. For new tires, the inventory level is based on the "sku".
2. For used tires, the inventory level is based on the attribute "tread depth", as if identified by "sku+depth".
3. When user searches for "sku", both new and used tires should come up.

I know configurable product is a solution but wonder if anyone has a simpler approach or extension. Thanks!

Comment: Configurable products sounds ideal for your scenario. What simplifications were you hoping to find? You get a lot of benefits from working with existing Magento data structures, so maybe you just need some workflow improving extensions?

Comment: Thanks for commenting. Configurable products works nicely but data entry process is kinda painful. Also, used tires of the same sku are almost always small in quantity, say Dunlop SP10 with 90% tread left, price is $100, and inventory is 2. Dunlop SP-10 with 80% tread left, price is $90, and inventory is 1 etc. The scenario is quite volatile to keep up with.

Comment: Understood. As I suspected, you may want to look more in the direction of workflow improvements like [Enhanced Product Grid](https://amasty.com/extended-product-grid-with-editor.html), [Magmi: Magento Mass Importer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/magmi/), etc.